# Loading projects using Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices throws System.ArgumentNullException for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, roslyn, vsix, roslyn-code-analysis

I am trying to enumerate all projects of a solution using Microsoft.VisualStuio.LanguageServices.
This is working fine for VisualStudio 2019 but it is failing on VisualStudio 2017.
My code is as bellow-

```
var workspace= ComponentModel.GetService<Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.VisualStudioWorkspace>(); 
var projects = workspace.CurrentSolution.Projects;
```

I am getting exception in the second line -

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source'

It shows list of projects on debug though.
I am using Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.dll of 2.10.0.0 version which is same as loaded dll in  VS module.
Is it a assembly issue? How can I fix this?

Comment: based on my test, I find that I can not use the code you provided. Can you tell me what reference you added or nuget-package you added?

Comment: I just figured out the issue. Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageService.dll version 2.10.0 was not compatible with 3.7.0.0 version of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll that I was referring. Visual Studio 2017 uses Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll version 2.10.0.0, though it does not load in Module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue happened due to mismatch versions of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis between referenced dll and VS2017's dll.

In the module window it was clearly visible that, VS is using Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices 2.10.0.0, hence I kept the reference dll of same version.

In this statement-
`var workspace= componentModel.GetService<Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.VisualStudioWorkspace>();` 
workspace is of type Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.VisualStudioWorkspace.

But when we do this - `var projects = workspace.CurrentSolution.Projects;`

the type of variable 'projects' is IEnumerable<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Project>

I suppose, that is the reason while debugging the value was available in quick watch but failed in to execute.

Solution - refer dlls of same version as referred by VS.